# Which meaning of 意见 in used in 他经常到客户不听取意见 and 如果有人愿意听取客户的意见?

Tags: meaning

Talking about 王嘉廉， I have:

他经常到客户不听取意见，并受到了很大的启发。电脑界最大的弊端是仅靠技术为驱动力，科技人员从不聆听客户的需求。如果有人愿意听取客户的意见，必定会有很大的发展机会。

I‘m pretty sure that '意见' is 'complaints' here, but I suppose it could just as easily be 'ideas' or 'suggestions'.

Is there any way to be sure?

Comment: this sentence seems to be missing some characters? - `他经常到客户不听取意见`

Answer (score 2):

Here it means `suggestions`.

From `新汉英大辞典`:

```
意见 [yì jian]
1.
（看法或想法） idea; view; opinion; suggestion:
a clash of opinions;
意见冲突
make suggestions for revision;
提出修改意见
2.
（反对或不满意） objection; differing opinion; complaint:
I have a lot of complaints about her.
我对她很有意见。
If there is no objection, the agenda is adopted.
如果没有意见， 议程就通过了。
```

BTW: `客户不` should be `客户部`.

Comment: My book has '客户部‘ I just checked.  On what basis do you say it should be 'suggestions'? Maybe you mean the second one is 'suggestions'??

Answer (score 2):

**KEY**

> 听取意见
>
> listen to opinions or suggestions

`对 xxx 有意见` is the most likely construct where 意见 would mean complaints or objections.

Or:

ABC

> 很有意见
>
> hěn yǒu yìjian
>
> strongly object

意见很大 is also a likely variant for complaints or objects.

It would be very unlikely to hear 听取意见 used for complaints though.

Comment: 客户箱 = customer suggestions box
客户意见箱 = customer comments and suggestions box.
May be a veiled description of a complaints box!

Answer (score 1):

客户的意见可以理解为反馈（feedback），这些反馈通常是一些对产品有帮助的想法，那些人很可能带着愤怒和指责的情绪。